# Very large float division options python

Tags: python, scipy

I was just wondering what options are available in python for very large float division results.  i.e 1000 digit var / 1000 digit var.

I have tried GMPY2 but when used receive the "Exception has occurred: OverflowError
integer division results too large for a float" Is there a workaround here?

I'm now looking at the fraction module.  Any other suggestions would be great.  Many Thanks

Comment: What kind of result are you hoping to get? In particular, how much precision do you need? What will you do with the result? For example, I can write `10**1000 / 10**999` and get `10.0` with no issue, even though those values will not fit in a float.

Comment: Usually, this kind of situation means you should be working in terms of logarithms instead of your original numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm working with high-digit and precision results.  Regularly hitting 1000-digit results so the float is a must. Johan pretty much answered my question.  But thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably still use gmpy2. Try using the  `gmpy2.div()` function instead of the regular division operator to avoid the overflow error. (Documentation here: https://readthedocs.org/projects/gmpy2/downloads/pdf/latest/ mentions it) :

```
import gmpy2

gmpy2.get_context().precision = 1000  # Set the precision

num1 = gmpy2.mpz('1' + '0' * 999)  # A 1000-digit number
num2 = gmpy2.mpz('2' + '0' * 998)  # A 1000-digit number

result = gmpy2.div(num1, num2)

print(result)
```

You can also use the built-in `decimal` module in Python. (https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) It provides a `Decimal` data type (https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) with user-defined precision. Here is example of how you can use it with 1000 digit precision.

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

# Set the precision to the desired number of decimal places
getcontext().prec = 1000

num1 = Decimal('1' + '0' * 999)  # A 1000-digit number
num2 = Decimal('2' + '0' * 998)  # A 1000-digit number

result = num1 / num2

print(result)
```

The precision is set with `getcontext().prec`. Remember the higher the number is the more memory it uses. For a 64-bit system the typically highest precision you can have is 9223372036854775807 digits. In python you can check how much your machine can handle with `print(sys.maxsize)` after importing the `sys` module. But anything near that would be incredibly slow.

Comment: https://mpmath.org/ is widely used in python, including in `sympy`.  Apparently it is a wrapper to either `gmpy` or `gmpy2`.

Comment: Thanks, Johan,  The issue with gmpy2 was I should have used the generic functions of add, div, etc.  I must have missed it in the web version of the documentation as it was there in the pdf version I downloaded.  May thanks and will look into the decimal as well.